# Is it possible to load the same message from AWS SQS more than once

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS FIFO queue which we send bunch of ids for processing on the other end. We have 4 workers digesting the message. Once the worker receives the message, it deletes the msg and stores these ids until it hits a limit before performing actions.

What I've noticed is that some ids are received more than once when each id is only sent once. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

Your current process appears to be:

- A worker pulls (Receives) a message from a queue
- It deletes the message
- It performs actions on the message

This is not the recommended way to use a queue because the worker might fail after it has deleted the message but before it has completed the action. Thus, the message would be "lost".

The recommended way to use a queue would be:

- Pull a message from the queue (makes the message temporarily invisible)
- Process the message
- Delete the message

This way, if the worker fails while processing the message, it will automatically "reappear" on the queue after the invisibility period. The worker can also send a "still working" signal to keep the message invisible for longer while it is being processed.

Amazon SQS FIFO queues provide **exactly-once processing**. This means that a message will only be delivered once. (However, if the invisibility period expires before the message is deleted, it will be provided again.)

You say that "some ids are received more than once". I would recommend adding debug code to try and understand the circumstances in which this happens, since it should not be happening if the messages are deleted within the invisibility period.